# reference my XML in a function using 'this'

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, this

I have the following script to look up an XML file and produce an ordered list. The result is displayed in a div box and each item in the list can be selected by the user. When an item in the list is clicked, the function '**selected()**' will be called.

This all works fine, I can list the data and the user can select. The problem is that I want to populate a form with the XML results and need to reference the selected items , I thought that I could use `this` but I am getting errors. Can anyone offer some advice please?

I have omitted some of the code that displays the div boxes etc.

```javascript
function searchaddress() {
    searchstring = $('#nam').val();
    chr = searchstring.length;

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({ type: "GET",
                 url: "../241/NEWsearch_action.php?ss=" + searchstring ,
                 dataType: "xml",
                 success: searchxml });
    });
} 

// data returned from AJAX.php 
function searchxml(data) {
    var display = "";
    var msg = "";
    var currentWidth = 25;

    $(data).find('NameSearch').each(function() {
        numres = $(data).find('NameSearch').length;
        coursename = $(this).find('sitelist').text();
        address1 = $(this).find('address1').text();
        address2 = $(this).find('address2').text();
        postcode = $(this).find('postcode').text();
        number1 = $(this).find('number1').text();

        string = "<b> <a onclick='selected(" + **this** + ")' > " + coursename < /br> " ; 
        msg += string;
    }); // find loop
    $('#UniDivBody').html(msg);
}

function selected(e) {
    coursename = $(e).find('sitelist').text();
    // REFERENCE THE SELECTED DATA HERE???
}
```

Comment: That's a weird place for your jQuery document-ready function, all up in that other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly place this line

```
numres = $(data).find('NameSearch').length ;
```

outside the `.each` call because you are setting `numres` value everytime the `.each` function loops through your NameSearch.

Secondly

why not use delegate to delegate your click event.

```
$('#UniDivBody').delegate('a','click',function(){
    //declare the clicked <a>
    var $element = $(this),
    l_element = this;
    //this is going to pass through the <a> to the selected function
    selected(this);
})
```

Do you have a live example?